# Excluding millions of records on Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I have a Tableau data source with about 30 millions of records in just a row and I have 14 different Excel files with one column each, meaning having approximately 14 millions of records. I want to exclude these 14 millions of records from the data source and I couldn't find a way to exclude them and execute a query. As an output, I need the difference, 30 - 14 = 16 millions of records. How can I get the desired output?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Please provide us with more information to better help you. For reference on how to produce a minimal reproducible example, visit the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A Tableau data source is really meta-data that points to (connects to, describes) data that exists elsewhere. (Unless you have a naked extract) Where is your actual data stored?